# Filtered Unique Index causing UPDATE to fail because incorrect 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER' settings

Tags: sql, sql-server, unique-index, filtered-index, quoted-identifier

We've put in place the following filtered index on a table in our SQL Server 2016 database:

```
    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [fix_SystemPKeyExecutionOrder] ON [DataInt].[TaskMaster]
(
    [SystemPkey] ASC,
    [ExecutionOrder] ASC
)
WHERE ([ExecutionOrder] IS NOT NULL)
WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95)
GO
```

Which is causing SQL code to fail now with the following error:

> UPDATE failed because the following SET options have incorrect
>   settings: 'QUOTED_IDENTIFIER'. Verify that SET options are correct for
>   use with indexed views and/or indexes on computed columns and/or
>   filtered indexes and/or query notifications and/or XML data type
>   methods and/or spatial index operations. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error
>   1934).  The step failed.

When the filtered index is removed, the code runs perfectly.

Looking on [MSDN for Index Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869(v=sql.110).aspx), there's nothing about QUOTED_IDENTIFIERS.

None of the UPDATE statements in our SQL code have double quotes for any of the values. The only double-quotes we can see are the following:

```
SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT

    If (@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The "File Import" task ACTIVE_YN could not be updated to "Y". Either the task does not exist or the system "File Import To Stage" does not exist.', 16, 1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Print 'Successfully updated the "File Import" task ACTIVE_YN to "Y".'
    END
```

Even if we change those double quotes " to two single quotes '', the code still fails with the same error.

The table itself was created with:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [DataInt].[TaskMaster](
    [Pkey] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ScheduleMasterPkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SystemPkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [SourcePkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TargetPkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskName] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [TaskTypePkey] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Active_YN] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [RowVersion] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [ExecutionOrder] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Table1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Pkey] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY],
 CONSTRAINT [uc_TaskName] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [TaskName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 95) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Like I said though, the entirety of the code runs perfectly if we do not create the filtered index; it only fails with the index.

**So why is the filtered index suddenly causing our SQL to bomb and how can we fix it?**

**UPDATE:** here is a small snippet of code that reproduces the failure. This code is run through an SQL Agent Job. When the index is removed, this code runs as expected stating the error the task does not exist:

```
DECLARE @ROWCOUNT INT = 0

UPDATE [DataIntegrationMaster].[DataInt].[TaskMaster]
    Set Active_YN = 'Y'
    where TaskName = 'File Import'
    and SystemPkey = 0

    SET @ROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT

    If (@ROWCOUNT = 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('The "File Import" task ACTIVE_YN could not be updated to "Y". Either the task does not exist or the system "File Import To Stage" does not exist.', 16, 1)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        Print 'Successfully updated the "File Import" task ACTIVE_YN to "Y".'
    END
```

**UPDATE2 with ANSWER:**
As pointed out by the helpful answers below, I had to put

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

at the top of the SQL for it to work properly.

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
```

has NO EFFECT when I use it creating the index.

Comment: Are you able to create a minimal but self contained script that we can use to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Updated question with code snippet that causes error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is: [SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)

In order to prevent similar issues, I would recommend to check the exact requirements for creating a filtered index: [CREATE INDEX (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188783.aspx). It has a nice neat table that shows `SET` options required for a filtered index to be created.

Comment: Good link @Roger. I wonder why MSDN couldn't put that information on the same page as the one the OP linked to.

Comment: I had to put `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` at the top of the SQL that was actually doing the update; if I put `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` in the creation of the index it had no effect. Now it's working. Thank you for teh link. That was a MSDN good link. I find it annoying that any SP or other SQL written now that touches that table has to have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` explicitly set.

Comment: You can try to set this option `ON` by default on the server level, thus minimising the impact on the existing code. Unless this option is explicitly set to `OFF` somewhere, everyone will pick up the server default.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in @Roger Wolf's answer, creating a filtered index requires you to have the `QUOTED_IDENTIFER` setting to be set to `ON`, which is what you did.  Had you not done so, you would have been unable to create the filtered index in the first place.

However, once created, it would seem that any DML operation (not just updates) on that table require you to have the `QUOTED_IDENTIFER` setting to be set to `ON` as well.  This is what you are currently missing, and the reason why you get the error.

So, I don't know what the context of your `update` is, whether you are running this as an ad-hoc statement, or if this is part of a stored procedure. Either way, make sure to include the `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` statement somewhere at the beginning.

Comment: Thanks for your update. I upvoted you, but gave @Roger the answer credit since he had the link with the info first. As you say, I had to put `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` in the SQL. That SQL is a regular agent job. I find it annoying that any SP or other SQL written now that touches that table has to have `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON` explicitly set.